# React Radio Button Value doesn't change on form submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, radio-button

I have a signup form with 2 radio buttons and on submitting it should post the value depending on your selection. It only posts the value of the first radio button, even If the second radio button is selected. Below code is partial and not the full code, only where my radio button takes place in my component. I also have other fields in the form I didn't include it in here and the first field is `first_name: e.target[0].value` up to `roles: e.target[8].value` Thanks

```
const [register, setRegister] = useState({roles: ''})

const handleOnSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault()
const userData = { roles: e.target[8].value }
setRegister({ ...register, loading: true })

const handleOnChange = e => {
    setRegister({ ...register, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

<form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} className={classes.form} noValidate>

 <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="roles" value={value} onChange={handleOnChange}>
 <FormControlLabel name="roles" value="tutor" control={<Radio />} label="Tutor" />
 <FormControlLabel name="roles" value="student" control={<Radio />} label="Student" />
 </RadioGroup>

 <Button
   type="submit"
   fullWidth
   variant="contained"
   color="primary"
   className={classes.submit}
   >
   Sign Up
   </Button>
</form>
```

Comment: is handleOnSubmit complete ? what is the use of userData ?
is this not working- `const handleOnSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault()
setRegister({ ...register, loading: true })}`

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't add all my fields as they work fine. `handleOnSubmit` will submit my form with those values in the state which is register in this case. 

userData is a variable that holds those objects/data and passes them down with Axios `axios.post(`${wpSiteUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/users`, userData`

My component has a lot of code and no point adding all of my code here, only radio buttons that not working properly.